# Persistence of Publishing

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using the google cloud PubSub Java client libaries and have a basic question about publishing guarantees. In the code below, if the publish returns successfully, i.e., the code gets to the `// do other processing` part, is the message guaranteed to be safely on Google's servers? Do I need to check the returned messageId?

BTW, I know about the ApiFutures.addCallback to add a success/failure callback, but I'd rather not do that.

```
Publisher myPublisher = ...
PubsubMessage myMessage = ...

try {
  String messageId = myPublisher.publish(myMessage).get();
  // do other processing
} catch(Exception e) {
  // do error handling
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `.get()` on the future returns, it is guaranteed that Cloud Pub/Sub has received the message and will deliver it to interested subscribers. Note that if you are going to use `.get()` immediately like this and you aren't going to share a publisher instance across threads, you should set the max messages in the [batching settings](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#batching) to 1. Otherwise, you will have an extra delay in sending the message to Pub/Sub as the client will attempt to fill the batch for up to the max latency setting amount of time. If you aren't making multiple calls in parallel, nothing will ever get batched and so the time waiting will have been wasted.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and the heads up on the batching settings - I'll have to look into what our settings for that are.

Comment: A corrolary question: If we successfuly get() on a list of futures, are all the messages guaranteed to be receive by Pub/Sub as well: `var future1 = myPublisher.publish(myMessage1);
var future2 = myPublisher.publish(myMessage2);
var futures = List.of(future1, future2);
List<String> messageIds = ApiFutures
        .allAsList(futures).get(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
`

Comment: Yes. A get on a list of futures completes successfully only when all of the individual futures' gets would complete successfully.